# SQL - Add column values depending on id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with million records. The following is an example of one group of data:

```
select id, 
       id_depend, 
       Item, 
       values as 'Current Values' 
from mytable 
where id in (685690, 691282, 691297) 
order by 1
```

[image]

The first id (685690) correspond to a first movement, the second one (691282) cancel the first movement and the third is the correction of the first movement. The **id_depend** field relates the movements with the original.

I need to show the same data adding a new column with the values for the last movement related. I mean, sometimes the first movement (other ids) is rigth and ther is no corrections after this movement (e.g.: id 691371).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help if I understand it correctly:

```
SELECT m.id,m.id_depend,m.Item,m.[values] [Current Values]
    ,CASE WHEN m.id_depend = 0 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mytable cor WHERE cor.id_depend = m.id)
        THEN m.[values] 
        ELSE COALESCE((SELECT SUM(mt.[values]) FROM mytable mt WHERE mt.Item = m.Item AND mt.id < m.id)+m.[values],0) 
     END [Values Required]
FROM mytable m
```

There is also my query to play with:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable (id BIGINT, id_depend BIGINT, Item VARCHAR(50), [values] DECIMAL(23,10))

INSERT INTO #mytable (id,id_depend,Item,[values])VALUES(685690,0,'1',216),(685690,0,'2',108)
    ,(691282,685690,'1',-216),(691282,685690,'2',-108)
    ,(691297,685690,'1',324),(691297,685690,'2',162)
    ,(691371,0,'1',100),(691371,0,'2',200),(691371,0,'3',300)

SELECT m.id,m.id_depend,m.Item,m.[values] [Current Values]
FROM #mytable m

SELECT m.id,m.id_depend,m.Item,m.[values] [Current Values]
    ,CASE WHEN m.id_depend = 0 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #mytable cor WHERE cor.id_depend = m.id)
        THEN m.[values] 
        ELSE COALESCE((SELECT SUM(mt.[values]) FROM #mytable mt WHERE mt.Item = m.Item AND mt.id < m.id)+m.[values],0) 
     END [Values Required]
FROM #mytable m

DROP TABLE #mytable
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.